# sql statement for join two tables with and condition

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have two tables with multiple records for `StaffID` in `StaffDesignation` table and i need unique values.

```
select * from StaffMst where StaffID in (select StaffID from StaffDesignation where DesignationID in (6,9))
```

which means 'or' condition (6 or 9) both records will come, but i need 'and' condition (6 and 9), how to get this?

Comment: look up `group by` and `having` clauses for SQL

Comment: select * from staffmst sm
inner join staffDesignation sd on sm.staffId=sd.staffid
group by staffId

Comment: i want the StaffMst record for all staff with both the 6 and 9 designation and it should me comma separated like (1,2,3,6,9)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is a "set-within-sets" subquery.  If you want the `StaffMst` record for all staff with both the 6 and 9 designation:

```
select m.*
from StaffMst m join
     StaffDesignation sd
     on m.StaffId = sd.StaffId
group by m.StaffId
having sum(sd.DesignationId = 6) > 0 and
       sum(sd.DesignationId = 9) > 0;
```

Each condition in the having clause is counting the number of one type of designations.  The `> 0` means that at least one exists.  So, the above checks for both.

If you want either, then you can change the `and` to `or`:

```
select m.*
from StaffMst m join
     StaffDesignation sd
     on m.StaffId = sd.StaffId
group by m.StaffId
having sum(sd.DesignationId = 6) > 0 or
       sum(sd.DesignationId = 9) > 0;
```

Comment: DesignationID will be comma separated (1,2,3)

Comment: No accounting for bad database design.  You should fix the database, by adding a junction/association table.